# server.sh not found when establishing vscode remote ssh connection

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I get the following error when connecting to a remote host to setup remote SSH connection.

> Server did not start successfully. Full server log >>>
>
> [09:58:46.599] > bash: line 212: /u/kasula/.vscode-server/bin/036a6b1d3ac84e5ca96a17a44e63a87971f8fcc8/server.sh: No such file or directory
>   <<< End of server log

Not sure how to proceed, and no more information in the log file or terminal.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue too.
My local OS is macOS 10.15.4, and the remote OS is CentOS 8.

It turns out that CentOS 8 doesn't installed tar as default. So I just install it (`sudo yum install tar`), and then connect to remote again in VSCode and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

The server.sh file is nowhere to be found.

```
[18:10:19.668] > Server did not start successfully. Full server log >>>
> bash: line 302: /root/.vscode-server/bin/26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c
> 0/**server.sh: No such file or directory**
> <<< End of server log
```

- **Update after solving the issue:**

In my case, VSCODE couldn't download the server.sh file. I gave the linux server permission to download from these two sites and the problem was solved.

**update.code.visualstudio.com**  or (https://visualstudio.com with all prefixes)

**vo.msecnd.net**  or (https://msecnd.net with all prefixes)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You have a new question, ask it as a separate question.

Comment: You're right. I updated the answer after finding a solution.

Comment: How did you give linux server permission to download it?